# CodeIgniter update record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Controler

```
//class News
public function update($slug)
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $data['news_item']=$this->news_model->get_news($slug);
    if (empty($data['news_item']))
    {
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('news/update', $data);
    //$this->load->view('save',$save);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

Model new_model.php

```
//class News_model
public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
{
    if($slug === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('news');        
        return $query->result_array(); 
    }
    $query = $this->db->get_where('news',array('slug'=>$slug));
    return $query->row_array();
}
public function update_news($slug)
{
    $query=$this->db->where('slug', $slug);
    $this->db->update('news' ,$query);
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

in update.php view file code given below..
view update.php file

```
<h2>Update New Item</h2>
```

```
<?php echo form_open('news/update') ?>

<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="input" name="title" value="<?php echo $news_item['title']; ?>" readonly/><br>

<label for="text">Text</label>
<textarea name="text" cols="35" rows="16"><?php echo $news_item['text'];?></textarea><br>

<a href="save/">save</a>

</form>
```

data will be fetch but problemb is that when i click on "save" link page not found error generatos why?
how can call this view save.php file..

Comment: what are you doing in this code? i cant understand. Can you explain?

Comment: To save the form, just put a submit input, like <input type="submit" value="save" />, the a link will just redirect the page to another url.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<a href="save/">save</a>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="save" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have used link in-place of submit button. 
When you use submit button it will post/get data on url that is there in the form action.
Here you can use :

```
<?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit Post!'); ?>
```

It will produce...

```
<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit Post!" />
```

For more details : [Form Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)